# How does stream.Readable.prototype.on handle events in node.js source code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was confused when reading code of `stream.Readable` in `Node.js`.

here is source code:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L778-L799

```
Readable.prototype.on = function(ev, fn) {
  const res = Stream.prototype.on.call(this, ev, fn);

  if (ev === 'data') {
    // Start flowing on next tick if stream isn't explicitly paused
    if (this._readableState.flowing !== false)
      this.resume();
  } else if (ev === 'readable') {
    const state = this._readableState;
    if (!state.endEmitted && !state.readableListening) {
      state.readableListening = state.needReadable = true;
      state.emittedReadable = false;
      if (!state.reading) {
        process.nextTick(nReadingNextTick, this);
      } else if (state.length) {
        emitReadable(this);
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
};
```

Obviously, the `if` statements only handle `data` and `Readable` event, but according to the [API document](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), the `on` method of `stream.readable` also accept other events such as `close` , `end` , `error`.

So my question is :

**According to the source code, how did `stream.Readable` handle other events except `data` and `readable`?**

Comment: `const res = Stream.prototype.on.call(this, ev, fn);` Only `data` and `readable` events are specific to the `Readable` stream, rest of them are handled by the base class `Stream`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for your    comment. I noticed this statement but didn't realize it pass ev argument to Stream.on method. I am clearly about the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing here is an override for the `.on()` method so that the `Readable` class can watch what event listeners are being attached and can do something special when someone installs a listener for the `data` event or the `readable` event.

The first line of this function:

```
const res = Stream.prototype.on.call(this, ev, fn);
```

is where the Readable passes the callback and event name arguments to its parent so that the normal implementation will be run. A `Stream` implements the `EventEmitter` interface so calling the super method with `Stream.prototype.on.call(this, ev, fn)` will give `.on()` it's expected default behavior.

Then after calling the parent, it checks to see if the event that someone is listening to is the `data` event or `readable` event and then implements a little extra functionality when one of those event listeners is attached.

For the `data` event, it resumes the stream so that it will start flowing if it was paused and if it was set to flowing mode.  This is probably because when a `Readable` is being initially created and configured, if it starts flowing the stream before the `data` event listener is attached, then data on the stream could be missed.  So, it doesn't start flowing until someone is around to listen to `data` events.

Note, there are potentially lots of over events that occur on the stream and those are all handled by the call to the base class in the first line.  What you are seeing here is just some special behavior that the `Readable` class wants to implement when two specific event listeners are first added.  This code does not affect when those events are sent or how they are listened to.  It just triggers a little behavior in the `Readable` state when a listener for one of these events is first attached.

Comment: @L.Dezhi - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did.Thanks for your answer:)